# ValueError: cannot assign using Mock()

Tags: python, django, mocking

I'm learning how to use Mock for testing in django (2.0.6 <= it can make the difference) but I'm stuck following a tutorial.

Here my `test_views.py`:

```
User = get_user_model() #I use this in other tests, I hope it don't interfere

@patch('lists.views.NewListForm')
class NewListViewUnitTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.request = HttpRequest()
        self.request.POST['text'] = 'new list item'
        self.request.user = Mock()

    def test_passes_POST_data_to_NewListForm(self, mockNewListForm):
        print('self.request', self.request.user)
        new_list2(self.request)
        mockNewListForm.assert_called_once_with(data=self.request.POST)

[...]
```

And here my error on testing:

```
self.request <Mock name='mock()' id='80288792'> #print result
E
======================================================================
ERROR: test_passes_POST_data_to_NewListForm (lists.tests.test_views.NewListViewU
nitTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\python\Lib\unittest\mock.py", line 1179, in patched
    return func(*args, **keywargs)
  File "D:\progetti\superlists\lists\tests\test_views.py", line 149, in test_pas
ses_POST_data_to_NewListForm
    new_list2(self.request)
  File "D:\progetti\superlists\lists\views.py", line 42, in new_list2
    list_.owner = request.user
  File "C:\Users\fabio\.virtualenvs\superlist\lib\site-packages\django\db\models
\fields\related_descriptors.py", line 197, in __set__
    self.field.remote_field.model._meta.object_name,
ValueError: Cannot assign "<Mock name='mock()' id='80288792'>": "List.owner" must be a "User" instance.
```

So, it look like it don't recognize the `self.request.user = Mock()` like a User instance.

Note on the `test_view`:

1) the `print` command

2) the `User = get_user_model()` variable. `get_user_model()` comes from `django.contrib.auth`. I think it don't interfere.

I add some more code for completeness, ask for more if you need.

My views.py:

```
def new_list2(request):
    form = NewListForm(data=request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        list_ = List()
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            list_.owner = request.user
        list_.save()
        form.save(owner=request.user)
        return redirect(list_)
    return render(request, 'home.html', {'form': form})
```

My `forms.py`:

```
class ItemForm(forms.models.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = ('text',)
        widgets = {
            'text': forms.fields.TextInput(attrs={
                'placeholder': 'Enter a to-do item',
                'class': 'form-control input-lg',
            }),
        }
        error_messages = {
            'text': {'required': EMPTY_ITEM_ERROR}
        }

    def save(self, for_list):
        self.instance.list = for_list
        return super().save()

class NewListForm(ItemForm):

    def save(self, owner):
        if owner.is_authenticated:
            return List.create_new(first_item_text=self.cleaned_data['text'], 
                owner=owner)
        else:
            return List.create_new(first_item_text=self.cleaned_data['text'])
```

My `models.py`:

```
class List(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=True, null=True, 
        on_delete=models.PROTECT)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('view_list', args=[self.id])

    @staticmethod
    def create_new(first_item_text, owner=None):
        list_ = List.objects.create(owner=owner)
        Item.objects.create(text=first_item_text, list=list_)
        return list_

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self.item_set.first().text

    #def __str__(self):
    #    return self.item_set.first().text

class Item(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField(default='')
    list = models.ForeignKey(List, default=None, on_delete=models.PROTECT)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('id',)
        unique_together = ('list', 'text')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```

Please, any help will be appreciated

Comment: You need to look at the `List` model definition. The `owner` field is almost certainly a ORM relationship field that only accepts a `User` model instance. You'd have to make your mock pass the `isinstance()` test. *Or* you could use something like the factory_boy project to generate a `User` instance.

Comment: Alternatively, make the `if request.user.is_authenticated` test fail, by setting `self.request.user.is_authenticated = False` in your test `setUp` method.

Comment: I add the models.py and you are right, the List wants an User instance but Mock() shouldn't fakes one? I tried MagicMock(spec=User) and things like that but at not avail (sorry I'm newby, so I'm not sure what I'm doing). I want to test even an authenticated user. How can I make my mock pass the isinstance() test?

Comment: See [Mock class used in isinstance checks which has dynamic attributes](//stackoverflow.com/q/28997078) for something that fakes the class test.